# Как реализовать скрипт

Tags: mysql, циклы, sql

Помогите написать цикл для добавления множества пользователей разом вот метод добавления юзера

```
insert into mailbox values ('?', '?', '?', '?', 0, '?', '?', now(), now(), ?)
```

и таких пользователей мне нужно около 3 тысяч, как реализовать цикл в скрипте sql

Comment: И много тебе нужо пользователей, а имена откуда брать?

Comment: Уточните: знаки вопросов - это плейсхолдеры (вы исполььзуете PDO) и данные в каком виде приходят?

Comment: Хотя бы написал чем располагаешь? Php, java, python....

Comment: Если вам надо данные из одной таблицы(или таблиц) в другую перекинуть то воспользуйтесь  [insert select][1]


  [1]: http://phpclub.ru/mysql/doc/insert-select.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> скрипт написанный на чем угодно, главное чтобы работал

Значит покажу, как это можно сделать на php

> имена admin1,admin2,admin3... 3 тысячи

Предположу, что это строка, а не массив

```
$str = 'admin1,admin2,admin3,admin4,admin5,admin6,admin7,admin100500';
$user_arr = explode(',',$str);
$parts = array_chunk($user_arr,3); // можно разбить на несколько частей, напр. по 500.
foreach($parts as $p){
    $query = "INSERT INTO `mailbox` VALUES ";
    foreach($p as $val){
        $query .= "('".$val."@bar.ru', 'password', '".$val."', '".$val."@@bar.ru/', 0, '".$val."', 'bar.ru', now(), now(), 1),";
    }
    $query = substr($query, 0, -1);
    // тут запрос на запись в БД
}
```

Что получится - [можно глянуть тут](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/45g-hkc) (нажать **RUN** или **F9**). Только вместо выполнения запроса - выводим на эран.

Comment: варнинг: падаван детектед

Answer (score 1):

Можно [сгенерировать последовательность](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_number_sequence_generation.html), например, так:

```
SELECT CONCAT('user', 4*4*4*A + 4*4*B + 4*C + D + 1)
FROM
(SELECT 0 AS A UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) AS A CROSS JOIN
(SELECT 0 AS B UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) AS B CROSS JOIN
(SELECT 0 AS C UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) AS C CROSS JOIN
(SELECT 0 AS D UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) AS D
order by 4*4*4*A + 4*4*B + 4*C + D + 1
```

Для 3000 достаточно будет 10х10х10х3.